# luasocket 3.0,undefined symbol:lua_callk

Tags: luajit, luasocket

I'm using `luajit 2.0.3`,and I want to use luasocket in myproject.When require socket in `jit`, it reported an error

```
"error loading module 'socket.core' from file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/socket/core.so': /usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/socket/core.so: undefined symbol: lua_callk.
```

I compiled `luasocket 3.0` in `debian 5.0` with lua5.1.
I searched a lot of answers ,but none helped. I compiled luasocket 3.0 in debian 5.0 with lua5.1.

Answer (score 1):

LuaJIT is ABI-compatible with Lua 5.1, that means, you can compile a C module against the standard Lua headers and either load it from Lua or from LuaJIT.

Judging from the error message, LuaSocket requires the function `lua_callk`, however, as for today, this function is not implemented in LuaJIT. There has been requests of implementing this function as well as `lua_pcallk` and `lua_yieldk` but doing it so would require LuaJIT to switch to the Lua 5.2 ABI [1].

I would suggest you to switch to an older version of LuaSocket (2.0.2, for instance) or check whether LuaSocket can be compiled keeping 5.1 ABI compatibility.

[1] http://www.freelists.org/post/luajit/Yielding-across-C-boundaries,3